# Restar el valor de 2 inputs sin boton

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola tengo una funcion para multiplicar pero me gustaria qe fuera de resta, tengo 3 imputs
2 con la clase importe que se deben restar y otro con una clase  ventatotal, quisiera saber como podria poner el resultado ya que mi funcion nose como reestructrar para restar ya que mi funcion multiplica

```
var input=document.querySelectorAll(".importe");
input.forEach(function(e) {
   e.addEventListener("click",restar);
   e.addEventListener("keyup",restar);
});

// funcion que genera la resta
function restar() {

   // nos posicionamos en el tr del producto
   var tr=this.closest("tr");

   var total=1;

   // recorremos todos los elementos del tr que tienen la clase .input
   var inputs=tr.querySelectorAll(".importe");
   inputs.forEach(function(e) {
       total*=(e.value);

   });

   // mostramos el total con dos decimales
   tr.querySelector(".ventatotal").value=total.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: si cambias ese total*=(e.value) por total-=(e.value) debería de restar

Comment: si lo hice pero en vez de restar suma y el resultado lo pone como negativo

Comment: probablemente sea porque el valor que le estás pasando sea negativo? recordemos que restar un negativo lo vuelve positivo, además me imagino que total lo instancias como 1 para poder multiplicarlo desde el inicio, si vas a restar probablemente debas inicializar total con 0

Comment: No entiendo tu problema. Dices que ventatotal = importe1 - importe2 ???? o es otra formula???